# How to redirect from www to https www with htacces?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to do the following: 
My current address looks like: https://www.domain.com

I want to redirect with htaccess: 
www.domain.com TO https://www.domain.com and
http://domain.com TO https://www.domain.com

I've tried with some suggestions here, but it ended up with the endless loop. 
I tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE: I think I've done it with the following:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Is that the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a `!` infront of your domain name condition:

```
### Redirect non-www => www ###
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Because you want to say, do the next rule, if this condition matches... and the condition should be host does **NOT** match what you want.

If i mix this with techniques i have seen and used before, you could try this:

```
### Redirect non-www => www ###
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# redirect urls with index.html to folder
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*index.html HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index.html$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# change // to /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)//(.*) HTTP/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1/%2 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve both redirect in a single rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.yourdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: May I know why you removed acceptance after so many months? btw the other answer doesn't handle this case `http://www.domain.com => https://www.domain.com` and has many rules that are not even asked in question

Comment: I have a requirement described at this quetion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38645119/apache-mod-rewrite-all-incoming-urls-to-https-www. Using your answer I was able to achieve some of the redirects but not all. Could you provide your inputs

Answer (score 1):

The best way is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

With using `%{HTTP_HOST}` you don't need to write domain name

Answer (score 0):

Both nonWWW to WWW and http to https solutions:

```
## Redirecting HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

## Redirecting non WWW to WWW
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.tld$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.tld/$1 [R=301,L]
```