# How to edit htaccess to redirect all trafic to secure www domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

How to achieve the following:

- redirect all http:// domain .com to https:// www.domain .com
- redirect all http:// www.domain .com to https:// www.domain .com
- redirect all https:// domain .com to https:// www.domain .com

So basically, all my traffic be it non-www or www will be redirected to SSL www domain.

Edit:

Additionally, I have 2 subdomain that works on http, so I want to achieve the above and also keep the 2 subdomain free from the above redirect rule.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect from www to https www with htacces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29522778/how-to-redirect-from-www-to-https-www-with-htacces)

Comment: FYI (from Apache 2.4 [htaccess](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html) documentation): `You should avoid using .htaccess files completely if you have access to httpd main server config file. Using .htaccess files slows down your Apache http server.`

Comment: @Croises - the link that you gave is only for www to https www. what about the other 2 non-www to https www and https non-www to https www?

Comment: @vallismortis - I don't have access to httpd main server config file that is why i asked for a solution for htaccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code in Root/.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
#Http to https
#Exclude subdomains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(sub1|sub2)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,R]
#add www on ssl
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,R]
```

This will redirect :

- http://example.com
  or
- http://www.example.com

to ssl

- https://www.example.com

And the second rule will add www to non www requests on ssl, redirect :

- https://example.com

to

- https://www.example.com

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can edit your `httpd.conf` file, and add this to the :80 servers

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC]
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com$1 [L,R=301]
 </IfModule>
```

Anyway , this on `.htaccess` will do the same

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)      https://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R,NE]
```

Also, you can add in your vhost file also something like

`Redirect permanent / https://www.domain.com/`

And in your vhost_ssl:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                RewriteEngine On
                RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC]
                RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Redirect all http:// domain .com to https:// www.domain .com and redirect all https:// domain .com to https:// www.domain .com is Working. However redirect all http:// www.domain .com to https:// www.domain .com is not working for the above mentioned htaccess code.