# redirect all trafic to https://www.domain.com via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

My ssl works on https://www.domain.com and not on `https://domain.com` so I want to redirect https://domain.com to `https://www.domain.com`

I used the solution I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35101468/how-to-edit-htaccess-to-redirect-all-trafic-to-secure-www-domain) on how to edit htaccess to direct all traffic to a secure domain:

```
#Http to https
#Exclude subdomains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(sub1|sub2)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,R]
#add www on ssl
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,R]
```

However this does not work for the redirect of:

`https://domain.com` to `https://www.domain.com`

What is wrong here and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, I did try this but it doesn't work. Now I suspect a setting in DirectAdmin to be the culprit since the problem does not occur on another domain on the same server with a Let's Encrypt SSL certificate (instead of a SSL EV certificate on the problem domain) and the same .htaccess file.

Comment: According to my ISP the problem is caused by the fact that I have a ssl certificate for www.domain and not for domain (without www) so to solve it I need an extra ssl certificate. Getting to the redirect bit via an unsecure connection will not work (blocked by browser).