# How to redirect google VM external ip address to HTTPS in django with Debial and Apache?

Tags: django, apache, google-cloud-platform, debian, virtual-machine

I have successfully installed SSL certificate with certbot and lets encrypt on my debian and apache linux virtual machine on google cloud.

the domain is successfully secure with HTTPS.

Although on directly accessing the external ip address i am still getting an unsecure version of the website.
How to redirect the ip directly to the HTTPS version set up with APACHE and just the "domain.com" towards -->> HTTPs:www.domain.com .

I have tried to re-route to port 80 and 443 towards the HTTPS version as in PHP without any luck as shown here :
[How to redirect from www to https www with htacces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29522778/how-to-redirect-from-www-to-https-www-with-htacces?rq=1)

in my 000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName localhost
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.bracketline.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =localhost
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} 
[END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

and on my 000-default-le-ssl.conf i have:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>

ServerName localhost
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

Alias /static /var/www/static-root
<Directory /var/www/static-root>
 Require all granted
 </Directory>
Alias /media /var/www/media-root
<Directory /var/www/media-root>
 Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/venv/src/cfehome>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess cfehome python-            
path=/var/www/venv/src/:/var/www/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup cfehome
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/venv/src/cfehome/wsgi.py

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
ServerAlias www.bracketline.com
SSLCertificateFile 
/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.bracketline.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile 
/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.bracketline.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

I am not sure how this thing works if a detailed blog or turorial could be given it would be of great help. thanx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First lacate which `.conf` file youre actually using by typing `apachectl -S` (this works on Debian based OS'es).

Next up edit the file, it should look simillar:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com

  Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com

  Protocols h2 http/1.1

  # SSL Configuration

  # Other Apache Configuration

</VirtualHost>
```

In general there are several tutorials how to configure HTTP to HTTPS redirect:

- [Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Apache](https://linuxize.com/post/redirect-http-to-https-in-apache/)
- [How to Redirect HTTP to HTTPS on Apache](http://How%20to%20Redirect%20HTTP%20to%20HTTPS%20on%20Apache)
- [Apache Redirect to HTTPS](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9821/38/apache-redirect-to-https/)

And some interesting discusson [Why is my Apache VirtualHost directing to the wrong VirtualHost](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/why-is-my-apache-virtualhost-directing-to-the-wrong-virtualhost)?

Lastly - here's [another SO discussion on that topic that has an accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57343250/12257250).

Those are just recent (up to 2 years old) examples that will help you and there are dozens more if they won't answer your questions.