# How to Redirect HTTP to HTTPS on Apache?

Tags: apache, ssl, server, ssl-certificate, ubuntu-16.04

Environment: Ubuntu with Apache.

Trying to setup automatic redirection from http to https.

I have tried:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile    <path to your crt file>
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   <path to your private key file>

    # ...
</VirtualHost>
```

and

```
    RewriteEngine on
    ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R,L]
```

From mydomain.com --- To ---> (https://) mydomain.com

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to enable .htaccess in /etc/apache/sites-available/mydomain.conf, then create a .htaccess file in root directory (by default /var/www/html)  and write the code you have written above.

Comment: All of the answers given below are blindly following the OP's mistake of trying to use a rewrite to do a redirect. HTTP to HTTPS should be done with a redirect using the "Redirect" directive. No need to load the RewriteEngine with complicated rules, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you can access your website both through HTTP and HTTPS. Also make sure mod_rewrite is enabled, then you can add these lines to your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this code

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName foo.com
    ServerAlias www.foo.com

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl:s]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a virtual host based on this tutorial:
[Apache Web server - Setting Up Virtual Hosts](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-18-04#step-5-%E2%80%94-setting-up-virtual-hosts-(recommended))

Secondly you can create a Let's encrypt cert and if you use certbot it will automatically configures your Apache and do the redirection:
[How To Secure Apache with Let's Encrypt on Ubuntu 18.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-18-04)